# How to set the path of the default compiler in ./cshrc

Tags: csh

I am using a unix workstation with C shell. There were two compilers of mpif90, one compiled with ifort and one with gfortran, installed on the system. The default mpi compiler was the one compiled with gfortran.

Now, I want to change the default compiler to the ifort compiled one. It was stored in the folder "/usr/local/mvapich2-icc/bin". So I added the following to the ~/.cshrc file:

```
setenv mpif90 /usr/local/mvapich2-icc/bin/mpif90
```

and run "source ~/.cshrc" on the terminal. However, this seems not to have any effect. When I type "which mpif90", the path shown was still the gfortran compiled one.

How shall I set the environment properly so that the default compiler called was the ifort compiled one?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to just adjust the $PATH:

```
set path = (/usr/local/mvapich2-icc/bin $path)
```

However, this means that all executables in /usr/local/mvapich2-icc/bin/ will be found before the ones in your default path, which you might not want (I can't be sure).

Now, if you're compiling software with a Makefile, you'll probably be better off just defining the variables there to use the appropriate MPI compiler.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Finally I have added the link in the Makefile and everything goes smoothly. :)